# How to avoid last added 2 data in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

how to avoid last added 2 data in while loop

```
$counter = 0;
$data=mysql_query("select * from tbl_sub_product");
$cnt = sizeof(mysql_fetch_assoc($data));
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {


if(($counter==$cnt-1) || ($counter== $cnt-2)){

}
 echo $id = $row['id'];
}
```

is this a correct way.?is there any other way.? please help me

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated and not longer supported. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_*` instead. Also, you're not increasing your `$counter` value, what means that your `if` condition will always be false.

Comment: how i want to change my code.?

Comment: To make it work you can put a `$counter++;` right after your `echo`at the end. To change all the msql_ functions you have to go trough a tutorial. Here a really simple example: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php You should really change it. It will make your application faster and more secure.

Comment: try to use a mysql query rather than using logic in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be simple. Adding an additional condition within your `while` loop is not required at all, consider the solution below and Moreover `mysql_functions` are deprecated so I will suggest you to go with `mysqli_functions`

---

```
$count = 1;

/* Here $db would be something like $db = mysqli_connect('YOUR_HOST', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_NAME'); */
$data = mysqli_query($db, "select * from tbl_sub_product");

$rows_count = mysqli_num_rows($data);

while($count++ < $rows_count-2 && $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
     echo $id = $row['id']
}
```

That's all you have to do.

Comment: Is this not fetching the data on each iteration or the loop?

Comment: Yes it is fetching all the data and just not last two records which if wished can be fetch after running a loop again on `$data`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, as @Twinfriends said you should avoid using `mysql_` functions.

You need to actually increment your `$counter`. You can do this by `$counter++` (which is basically shorthand for `$counter = $counter + 1` or `$counter += 1`).

Also, as @jeroen pointed out, the way you're checking for the count would have

1. returned the first row of your results so it would be missing from your while loop.
2. Given you the column count rather than the row count.

With `mysql_` functions you need to use `mysql_num_rows()` for this.

```
$counter = 0;
$data = mysql_query("select * from tbl_sub_product");
$cnt = mysql_num_rows($data);

$stop = $cnt - 2;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {

    $counter++;

    if ($counter >= $stop) {
        break;
    }
    echo $id = $row['id'];
}
```

`break;` inside a loop with stop the loop there and then. If you have the situation where you want to skip an iteration but you don't want to stop the loop you can use `continue;` instead.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not correct: It will 1. skip the first row and 2. count the number of columns in a result row, not the number of rows in the result set.

Comment: @jeroen I didn't even see that. Good spot.

Comment: sry @Ross Wilson its avoided first added data. i want to delete last added data..

Comment: OP should use DB query modification rather than php logic

Comment: This is not "strictly" correct but the logic is there and everybody should understand how to resolve the problem :)

Comment: @user9394401 Sorry, I assumed you meant you wanted to ignore the last two entries in the array. Do you mean you want to ignore the last two entries that were added to the database?

Comment: yes..i want to remove last added 2 data.because last  added 2 data want to display some different style.

Comment: @Deep kakkar i tried a lot but i didn't get any solution.

Comment: @user9394401 In that case I would add an `order by` to your query to ensure that the results are in the right order. If you have it where the first 2 rows produced by the query are the ones you want to remove then change your if statement to `if ($counter < 3) { continue; }`

Comment: sorry @Ross Wilson  its also not working.i want result in asc orser

Comment: @user9394401 If your results are coming back in asc order then what I have in my answer should be working for you. Can you add an update to your question with the code you actually have now that isn't working?

Comment: $counter = 0;
$data=mysql_query("select * from tbl_sub_product ");
//$cnt = sizeof(mysql_fetch_assoc($data));
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
if(($counter < 5)){
echo $row['id'];
}
$counter++;
}

Comment: @user9394401 Tried the code I've put in my answer as what you've just posted is missing quite a few things from it...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
$counter = 0;
$data=
mysql_query("select* 
from tbl_sub_p    roduct");
$cnt =mysql_num_rows($data); 
 $run=$cnt-2;
while($row= 
mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
  $count++;


 if($count!=$run)

  {echo $id = $row['id'];
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: sory @Rohit Kumar its display all data.

Comment: @ Rohit Kumar thank you for your help.,i changed your code and i get what i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid last two entries added in database then simply modify your query to:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_sub_product ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,18446744073709551615");//it will start selecting from 3rd record and leave first two records in database which are actually last inserted records
```

Comment: He might get a problem if he have large number of rows in table

Comment: i want to display asc order. last added 2 data. i want to display this 2 data in a new style.old added data have another style. so i want to remove last added 2 data from this loop

Comment: Kindly update your problem with respect to your actual requirement

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer for my question

```
$counter = 0;
$data=mysql_query("select* from tbl_sub_product");
$cnt =mysql_num_rows($data); 
$run=$cnt-0;
$run1=$cnt-1;
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
$count++;
if($count!=$run && $count!=$run1)
{
echo $id = $row['id'];

}
}
```